# Can webpack package CSS into HTML as <style></style>?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Can a CSS file can be packaged into an HTML file as `<style>class..<style>` in `<header>` via webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can. Please take a look at [style-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/style-ext-html-webpack-plugin) webpack plugin.

The description on their readme is pretty good.

> This is an extension plugin for the Webpack plugin HtmlWebpackPlugin -
>   a plugin that simplifies the creation of HTML files to serve your
>   webpack bundles.
>
> The raw HtmlWebpackPlugin can bundle CSS assets as  elements if
>   used in conjunction with ExtractTextPlugin. This extension plugin
>   builds on this by moving the CSS content generated by
>   ExtractTextPlugin from an external CSS file to an internal 
>   element.

This plugin is used in combination with HtmlWebpackPlugin and ExtractTextPlugin plugins.